# Warning message not displaying when certain prices are less than cost price

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I am working on a React application where I have a form for managing prices. The form includes the following price types: Wholesale price, Transfer price, and Sales price. I want to display a warning message if the value entered for any of these prices is less than the cost price.

```
const COST_PRICE_TYPE = 'cost';
const SALES_PRICE_TYPE = 'sales';
const TRANSFER_PRICE_TYPE = 'transfer';
const WHOLESALE_PRICE_TYPE = 'wholesale';

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsTrue(true);

    if (updateData.isUpdate) {
      // ... (code for handling updates)

      const costPriceObject = priceList.find((item) => item.type.key === COST_PRICE_TYPE);
      const costPrice = costPriceObject ? costPriceObject.price : 0;

      const isSalesPriceLessThanCost =
      selectedPriceType.key === SALES_PRICE_TYPE && selectedPrice < costPrice;
      const isTransferPriceLessThanCost =
      selectedPriceType.key === TRANSFER_PRICE_TYPE && selectedPrice < costPrice;
      const isWholesalePriceLessThanCost =
      selectedPriceType.key === WHOLESALE_PRICE_TYPE && selectedPrice < costPrice;

      console.log('Cost Price:', costPrice);
      console.log('Is Sales Price Less Than Cost:', isSalesPriceLessThanCost);
      console.log('Is Transfer Price Less Than Cost:', isTransferPriceLessThanCost);
      console.log('Is Wholesale Price Less Than Cost:', isWholesalePriceLessThanCost);

      if (isSalesPriceLessThanCost || isTransferPriceLessThanCost || isWholesalePriceLessThanCost) {
        // Display a warning message
        const warningMessage = `Based on the amount for ${selectedPriceType.name} that is less than the    Cost price ${costPrice}, you may encounter a loss due to this.`;
        dispatch(showMessage({ message: warningMessage, variant: 'warning' }));
      }
    } else {
      // ... (code for handling new records)
    }

    setIsTrue(false);
    setUpdateData({ isUpdate: false, data: {} });
    setSelectedPrice('');
    setSelectedCurrencyUnit({});
    setSelectedPriceType({});
    resetField('priceType', 'currencyId');
    reset();
  };
```

The warning message is not displaying when a sales price, transfer price, or wholesale price is less than the cost price.

I have already tried adding console logs to check the values of costPrice, isSalesPriceLessThanCost, isTransferPriceLessThanCost, and isWholesalePriceLessThanCost, but the logs are not executed.

```
console.log('Cost Price:', costPrice);
console.log('Is Sales Price Less Than Cost:', isSalesPriceLessThanCost);
console.log('Is Transfer Price Less Than Cost:', isTransferPriceLessThanCost);
console.log('Is Wholesale Price Less Than Cost:', isWholesalePriceLessThanCost);
```

Comment: Quick question, where are the logs in relativity to the code above?

Comment: Is `updateData.isUpdate` ever true? That might be why the console.log statements are not executed

Comment: Check if selectedPriceType and selectedPrice have expected value by logging at start of submit method